# How to set group rows in NSTableView from Core Data Entity?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

My question is relevant to this one posted on StackOverflow.

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000753/create-group-rows-in-nstableview-using-coredata-backed-nsarraycontroller)

In iOS, NSFetchedResultController has section parameter which can get data from Core Data when an attribute is set as section **sectionNameKeyPath:**  while fetching attributes.

In Cocoa, NSTableView use **Floating Group Rows** to show section.
My managed object model contains two entity.

Entity 1

> Entity: Author
>
> Attribute: name

Entity 2

> Entity: Book
>
> Attribute: title

**Relationship** booksByAuthor is ToMany.

I want to show Author name in NSTable floating group row followed by Book titles by them in the row below.

To set group cell, I am using following tableView delegate methods

```
-(NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row;

-(BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView isGroupRow:(NSInteger)row;

-(CGFloat)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView heightOfRow:(NSInteger)row;
```

I am setting table view data using NSArrayController.

I searched for tutorials for this but there is not much available for Cocoa. I am new it so bear with me. I am stuck at this, could anyone help me on this. Do I need to alter my model object.

**Edit 1**

I tried this approach but the result is jumbled

```
-(NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
NSArray *bookTitleArray = [[self.bookArrayController arrangedObjects]valueForKey:@"title"];
NSArray *fromAuthorArray = [[self.bookArrayController arrangedObjects]valueForKey:@"fromAuthor"];
Author *authorName = fromAuthorArray[row];

NSMutableArray *testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (Author *auth in fromAuthorArray) {
    [testArray addObject:auth];
    for (Book *book in auth.books) {
        if (book.fromAuthor.name == auth.name) {
            [testArray addObject:book.title];
            
        }
    }
    
}


if ([testArray[row]isKindOfClass:[Author class]] ){
    NSTableCellView *newCell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"authorCell" owner:self];
    
    [newCell.textField setStringValue:authorName.name];
    return newCell;
}else if (![testArray[row]isKindOfClass:[Book class]]){
    NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"titleCell" owner:self];
    [cellView.textField setStringValue:bookTitleArray[row]];
    
    return cellView;
}
return nil;
}


-(BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView isGroupRow:(NSInteger)row{
    NSArray *fromAuthorArray = [[self.bookArrayController arrangedObjects]valueForKey:@"fromAuthor"];
    NSMutableArray *testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    
for (Author *auth in fromAuthorArray) {
    [testArray addObject:auth];
    for (Book *book in auth.books) {
        if (book.fromAuthor.name == auth.name) {
            [testArray addObject:book.title];
            
        }
    }
    
}



if ([testArray[row]isKindOfClass:[Author class]]) {
    return YES;
}else if ([testArray[row]isKindOfClass:[Book class]]){
    return NO;
}
return NO;
}
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot of NSTableView]

Comment: Show `arrangedObjects`-array creating/sorting code.

Comment: @Astoria, I have updated my question. In storyBoard I have set managedObjectContext and Entity.

Comment: This similar question has an answer: [Sectioned NSTableView using NSArrayController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443113/sectioned-nstableview-using-nsarraycontroller)